# How do I sort my files with fileupload on js when files show on the page?

Tags: javascript

I would like to sort my files with the [uploadfile](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) on js when files show on the page.

Does anyone know how it does that，please tell me !!

Here is part of my code

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    {           
        autoUpload: false,
        url: 'test.php',
        sequentialUploads: true,
        dataType: 'json',

        add: function (e, data) 
        {   
            console.log('add start');               

            filesList.push(data.files[0]);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) 
            {                                                           
                $('#presentation > .files').append(
                    $(
                    '<tr class="template-upload fade in">' +
                        '<td><span class="preview"><img src="' + e.target.result + '" class="previewImg" /></span></td>' +
                        '<td><input type="text" id="title' + num + '" class="name" value=' + data.files[0].name + ' data-name="'+ data.files[0].name +'" maxlength="30" title="max 30 words"><strong class="error text-danger"></strong></td>' +
                        '<td><p class="size">' + (data.files[0].size / 1000) + 'k</p></td>' +
                        '<td><button class="btn btn-warning cancel imgCancel" data-name="' + data.files[0].name + '"><span>cancel</span></button></td>' +
                    '</tr>'
                    )
                );                  
                num++;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(data.files[0]);};//end fileupload
```

Comment: Could you provide a small snippet (<>) where we can start?

Comment: sure，I just update

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to hook over the *add* method:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
 add: function (e, data) {
        //manipulate input
        data.formData = [...data.files].sort(/*whatever*/);

        //start original handler
        $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype
            .options.add.call(this, e, data);
  } 
});
```

Comment: Dear Jonas w
Is it necessary to add the "data.formData" to sort files?

Comment: No, with seing your code its just necccessary to do files = [...data.files].sort() , then work with files.

Comment: Dear Jonas w，would you please teach me more about this part " [...data.files]"，I am not sure what you mean，and I had try lots of way to sort the files that show on page，but it does not work.

Comment: It converts an array like ( the file list) into a real arry

Comment: Dear Jonas w,

I just found the key,the problem is not in the fileupload but in the filereader.
the fileupload is sorted from the beginning when the sequentialUploads is true.